# Can aircraft certified under the new EASA Part 21 Light "Declared process" be used for commercial operations?

Tags: flight-training, easa-regulations, commercial-operations, airworthiness

The new Part 21 Light for EASA member states includes a "declared" process for aircraft up to 1200 kg and two seats.  This process results in a restricted CofA for use in EU member states (see appendix i : https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32022R1358)

My question is, can this restricted CofA be used for commercial operations, namely flight training? EASA flight operations only stipulates that all aircraft must have a valid CofA, so normally this would be sufficient, however it would be good to have a second opinion.